# How to use CFrame to make the roblox player face the next checkpoint

Tags: lua, roblox

I was scripting the checkpoints of my roblox game and I wanted to make the player face the next checkpoint when it respawns, how can I do?

This is how the script looks now:

```
local checkpoints = workspace:WaitForChild("Checkpoints")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Value = 1

    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        wait()
        char:MoveTo(checkpoints[level.Value].Position)

        hum.Touched:connect(function(hit)
            if hit.Parent == checkpoints  then
                if tonumber(hit.Name) == level.Value + 1 then
                    level.Value = level.Value + 1
                end
            end
        end)
    end)
end)
```

checkpoints indicates the folder where the checkpoint parts are stored

That the player faces the next checkpoint when it respawns

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code does not work is that you put level.value + 1. In luaU, you can use =+. I modified your code and fixed your error. Also keep in mind that this section is not for roblox related scripts.

```lua
local checkpoints = workspace:WaitForChild("Checkpoints")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Value = 1

    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        wait()
        char:MoveTo(checkpoints[level.Value].Position)

        hum.Touched:connect(function(hit)
            if hit.Parent == checkpoints  then
                if tonumber(hit.Name) == level.Value =+ 1 then
                    level.Value = level.Value =+ 1
                end
            end
        end)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: Umm, i am not an expert on the changes Roblox made to lua but using the `=+` in side an if clause seems like a pretty bad idea, and doing `level.Value = level.Value =+ 1` should also be a really bad idea, in a generally sane language.

Comment: @Nifim Sorry, my mistake, in luau you can use level.Value =+ 1